# How to set the google plus counter at left of the G+ share button

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-plus, share-button

I want to set the counter in G+ share button at left of the button.
I am using the following code segment:

```
<div class="social-button-fixed" id="share-btn3">
<g:plus action="share" href="returnPageUrl()" annotation="bubble" height="60" align="left" expandTo="left"></g:plus>
</div>
<script >
  window.___gcfg = {
    lang: 'en-US',
    parsetags: 'onload'
  };
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

But it is showing the counter at right of the button:

[image]

How can I make it show at left?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/?hl=en

Comment: @Paulie_D That's +1 button, for share button the doc is this one: https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/
But it doesn't tell me how to position the counter...

Answer (score 0):

Change annotation to this "vertical-bubble" now counter will come on top and your layout will be divided into two row (before it was one row layout) now for tr tag give float left and width : 25% , now both will come in one line ,counter in left and G icon in right side now just adjust css like remove border from counter and use bubble image there, thats it.

Comment: How do you select the `tr`?

Comment: You can select tr like this   #widget_bounds tr {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The position of the counter is controlled with the [share tag attribute](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#sharetag-parameters) `annotation`. The annotation bubble supports two positions, `bubble` is to the right of the button and `vertical-bubble` is above. You can see [examples of the positions](https://jsbin.com/webufunece/edit?html,js,output).